# How to download file from web using request module?

Tags: python, download, python-requests

I am using python to download files from webpage, and after I submit the request, I get the headers like below:

```
>>> r.headers
{'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="report20160619-013623.csv";',
 'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'binary', 'Expires': '0',
'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5, max=100', 'Server': 'Apache',
'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'Pragma': 'public',
'Cache-Control': 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, private',
'Date': 'Sun, 19 Jun 2016 06:35:18 GMT', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}
```

My question is how could I download the `report20160619-013623.csv` using the `request` module.

I search around the web, there are solutions that download the file given a specific URL to that file, however, in my case, the file is generated on web by clicking something like "Download as excel". How do I know where the file is?

Answer (score 4):

You will read the response and then write it out as a file to a location you specify.

```
csv = r.text

outfile = open('/path/to/my.csv', 'w')
outfile.write(csv)
outfile.close()
```

Comment: OP specified that he would like to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module...

Comment: @GeorgeWang In my original response I used "example.com/downloads.csv" to just represent the path to the file you were downloading, but you already have a response containing that file.

Comment: @3kt Good point - I've rewritten my response to use the requests module

Comment: @climmunk, thank you very much for your help. I think I get a feeling how it works. But to confirm, report20160619-013623.csv here is useless, right? it can be replaced by customised name?

Comment: That's the default file name, and you can use it or change it.